# Chain of Calculated Columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm converting a financial spreadsheet into Pandas, and this is a frequent challenge that comes up.

In excel, suppose you have some calculation that for columns 0:n, the value depends on the previous column [shown in format Cell (row, column)]:  Cell(1,n) = (Cell(1,n-1)^2)*5.

Obviously, for n=2, you could create a calculated column in Pandas:

```
df[2] = (df[1]^2) *5
```

But for a chain of say 30, that doesn't work.  So currently, I am using a for loop.

```
total_columns_needed = list(range(0,100))
for i in total_columns_needed:
    df[i] = (df[i-1]^2)* 5
```

That loop works fine, but I trying to see how I could use map and apply to make this look cleaner.  From reading, apply is a loop function underneath, so I'm not sure whether I will get any speed from doing this.  But, it could shrink the code by a lot.

The problem that I've had with:

```
df.apply()
```

is that 1) there could be other columns not involved in the calculation (which arguably shouldn't be there if the data is properly normalised), and 2) the columns don't exist yet.  Part 2 could possibly be solved by creating the dataframe with all the needed columns, but I'm trying to avoid that for other reasons.

Any help in solving this greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To automatically generate a bunch of columns, without a loop:

```
In [433]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [0,1,2,3,4]})
In [434]:

print df.Val.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x+np.arange(0,25,5)))
   0  1   2   3   4
0  0  5  10  15  20
1  1  6  11  16  21
2  2  7  12  17  22
3  3  8  13  18  23
4  4  9  14  19  24
```

`numpy.arange(0,25,5)` gives you `array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20])`. For each of the values in `Val`, we will add that value to `array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20])`, creating a new `Series`.

And finally, put the new `Series` together back into a new `DataFrame`

Comment: Do you know of a more general method?  This works fine with basic addition, but I was trying to find a way to apply a more general function.  I've updated the question to show a more complicated example.

Comment: It can only be vectorized if we can write `df[i]` in a closed-form with regards to `i` and `df[0]`.  Even [Fibonacci Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) can be written in one.  You new example is not that difficult.  Essentially, `log(df[i]) = 2*log(df[i-1]) +log(5)`, or `log(df[i])+log(5) = 2*log(df[i-1]) +2*log(5)`. therefore `log(df[i])+log(5) = (df[0]+log(5))*(2**i)`.

Comment: ahhhhh ok.   So in the more complicated example I used, it would like something this?
    `df.Val.apply(lambda x:  pd.Series(x+log(x))*)2**i)`
How would you get i to "iterate" and use the i-1 value and specify the number of times to do this (without a for loop)?  I think the using .Val was a big help in understanding how to solve the problem because I didn't think of being able to reference a specific series within the df.